# Which data type is used to store DateTime in Oracle 10g?

Tags: java, oracle, oracle10g

Which data type is used to store date time (not only date but also time) in Oracle 10g database? I have read some where that (may be mistakenly) "*the Date data type in Oracle 10g can store date time*" but the thing doesn't seem to happen when I try to do so.

> The DATE datatype is a datetime datatype. It stores a date and a time.
>   The date portion is based on the number of days since January 1, 4712
>   BC. The time portion is based on the number of seconds since
>   mid-night. [The link](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/oracle-guide/learn-oracle-datatypes-for-sql-and-plsql-dates-10963)

I tried it through Java as a front-end and directly on the Oracle terminal using the following SQL.

```
insert into discount 
values(7, 'Code', 12.5, to_date('11-AUG-2012 06:05:23', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh:mi:ss'), 
to_date('20-AUG-2012 07:50:23', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh:mi:ss'))
```

It works but (in both the cases) Oracle simply ignores the time portion and inserts only the dates specified in the SQL without any error?

Which data type is used to store date time in Oracle 10g? Is it `TimeStamp`?

Comment: Personally I prefer `TIMESTAMP` or `TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE`

Comment: How do you say that Oracle ignores the time?

Comment: It always displays the time portion as `12:00:00` in my front-end, JSP where date time is formatted even though I enter the correct time portion other than this `12:00:00` and the time portion is not displayed at all on the Oracle prompt.

Comment: On the front side (Java), the solution found [here](http://www.enavigo.com/2007/10/20/mapping-hibernate-to-oracle-date-fields/) removing the `type="date"` attribute from the property mapping file `xxx.hbm.xml` of Hibernate. According to that solution,  if you include the *type attribute* with a value of either `date` or `timestamp`, it will not accurately convert the values.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A `DATE` in Oracle always has a day component and a time component.  Assuming the last two columns in the `DISCOUNT` table are declared as `DATE`, it is terribly unlikely that Oracle is simply ignoring the time component.

What makes you believe that the time component is being ignored?  My guess is that you are checking the data by running a query like

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM discount
```

from SQL*Plus, SQL Developer, TOAD, or some other GUI.  If you do that, by default, the date that is displayed will only have a day component and not a time component  That does not mean that the time component is being discarded.  Instead, it is the result of having a default `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` that doesn't display the time component.  You can force the time component to be displayed by doing an explicit `TO_CHAR` in your query, (note that I'm guessing at the names of your columns)

```sql
SELECT discount_id, 
       discount_type, 
       discount_amt, 
       to_char( discount_start_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS' ),
       to_char( discount_end_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS' )
  FROM discount
```

Or by changing your default `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET nls_date_format = 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS';
SELECT *
  FROM discount;
```

Comment: With the `to_char('...', '...')` function it retrieves the correct date time but after I applied `ALTER SESSION SET nls_date_format = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';`, it still just fetches the date portion on the Oracle terminal (with `SELECT *FROM discount;`). Is there a way to permanently specify the date-time format?

Comment: @Tiny - The `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is a client setting so each client and each session can have a different setting.  You shouldn't depend on the setting being anything in particular.  Potentially, you could create a login trigger that overrides the client setting for particular users.  Are you saying, though, that immediately after executing the `ALTER SESSION` that in the same SQL*Plus session you're not seeing the format change?

Comment: I can't oppose your statement but unfortunately I didn't notice it. May be I was doing something wrong. I will see it later. Thank you.

Comment: `ALTER SESSION` also worked correctly on the SQL command line. I was applying it on the *Oracle database web* (GUI) instead of applying on the `SQL command line` even though mentioned clearly in the answer. Felt so sorry.

Answer (score 4):

Oracle `DATE` does include the time as well. From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/datatype.htm#i1847%3a):

> **Overview of DATE Datatype**
>
> The DATE datatype stores point-in-time values (dates and times) in a
>   table. The DATE datatype stores the year (including the century), the
>   month, the day, the hours, the minutes, and the seconds (after
>   midnight).

It may be the tool(SQL Developer, SQL*Plus) you use that is cheating you. Try

```
select to_char(your_date, 'dd-mm-yy hh:mi:ss') from discount
```

Also note that the date datatype stores only till the seconds. [`TIMESTAMP`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#i53219) or [`TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#sthref125) are more precise.